# accessing Pandas dataframe by Excel cell index

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have imported an Excel spreadsheet into a dataframe. I wish to access data as though it was an Excel 
reference: e.g. df.get("A1") instead of df.iloc[0,0]. Does a nice method already exist for accessing dataframe data with Excel indexing - something like my imaginary get function above?

Comment: _Does a nice method already exist for accessing dataframe data with Excel indexing - something like my imaginary get function above?_ Not as far as I can tell, no, although it should't be too difficult to implement a helper function. Are the existing methods inadequate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a simple function to do the conversion from Excel index to numerical index:

```py
import regex as re

def index_transform(excel_index):
    match = re.match(r"^([a-z]+)(\d+)$", excel_index.lower())
    if not match:
        raise ValueError("Invalid index")

    x_cell = -1
    for idx, char in enumerate(match.group(1)[::-1]):
        x_cell += (26 ** idx) * (ord(char) - 96)  # ord('a') == 97

    y_cell = int(match.group(2)) - 1

    return y_cell, x_cell

# Usage
df.iloc[*index_transform("A1")]  # The * unpacks the returned tuple

# Example outputs
>>> index_transform("A1")
(0, 0)
>>> index_transform("E1")
(0, 4)
>>> index_transform("A5")
(4, 0)
>>> index_transform("e5")
(4, 4)
>>> index_transform("AA27")
(26, 26)
>>> index_transform("coffee1337")
(1336, 42608414)
```

Comment: Given my OP constraint stating I want to use Pandas, I accept above as the solution. However, I do think I'll go with xlswriter for my implementation. Thank you!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @goldfinger Can you please address my question regarding why you need to do this? Accessing specific elements is rarely necessary in Pandas, I'm both concerned and curious as what your use case is.

Comment: I am attempting to parse a hard-coded Excel spreadsheet, the contents of which might change. So I'm referencing a specified cell in the spreadsheet and verifying its contents as confirmation that the contents of the spreadsheet have not changed (by adding a row, for example, or changing a lebel).

Comment: Thanks! What is up with `import regex as re` though? For me just using the stdlib's `import re` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not Pandas but xlswriter does this: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html